# What are these pale blotchy spots on the new leaves of my draceana marginata?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, plant-care, tropical, dracaena

[image: Here is a picture of the new growth]

Recently, I decided to look at the new leaves of my dracaena that otherwise looks healthy and I've been surprised by this. I am wondering what are those stains and if they're bad for my plant. The dracaena is in a clay pot placed right in front of a south-facing window in Montreal, Canada. I might have seen a fungus gnat lurking around, but it doesn't seem like it has friends because after shaking all my plants, I can't see any. The dracaena drinks a lot and I sometimes need to water it twice a week because it's dirt becomes completely dry.

Thanks for your help in advance
Here's a picture from further :
[image]